# Netbeans 9 dark corrupted colors on toolbar menu

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-9

I have corrupted dark colors on the toolbar. I cannot see properly debugging icons.

[image]

I have tried to install the white theme to fix this problem. I have opened Tools/Plugins/Available plugins and search "light theme" but I cannot find theme.

```
Operating System   : Ubuntu LTS 18.04
Graphic Card       : Nvidia GTX 1050
Graphic Card Driver: nvdia-driver 396
```

Comment: It looks like the icons are disabled. Did you try to debug the project? They should automatically be enabled when the project is in debug mode

Comment: They remain the same when I try debugging.